# Pandas Column and Row exists

Tags: python, pandas

This is going to be hard for me to explain....but here I go...

I have two CSV files that I load in via PANDAS, but they are not the same "shape"
We shall call then CSV1 and CSV2

I take two values from CSV1 and check to see if they exist in CSV2 
We shall call the values VAL1 and VAL2; they are all floating point numbers to three decimal points.

assuming it exists in CSV2, VAL1 should be located somewhere in the first "column".

assuming it exists in CSV2, VAL2 should be an actual column header

For testing purposes i have ensured that the data in the two files are like-for-like, however when i run the scrip it is not finding a match on *most* of the values

```
import pandas as pd

_new = pd.read_csv('02 dump/reputation.csv', sep=';', float_precision='round_trip')
_data = pd.read_csv('00 data/confdata.csv', sep=';', float_precision='round_trip')

def confupdate():
    print(a)
    print("update")

def confnew():
    print(a)
    print("added")



for a,b in zip(_new['LAT'].values, _new['LON'].values): 
    print(a, b)

    if str(a) in str(_data['LAT'].values) and str(b) in str(_data.columns):

        confupdate()

    if str(a) not in str(_data['LAT'].values) and str(b) not in str(_data.columns):

        confnew()

    if str(a) not in str(_data['LAT'].values) or str(b) not in str(_data.columns):

        confnew()
```

I think it has something to do with float_precision='round_trip' in that it only affects how my floating point number is *displayed* though in the background the numbers are still not matching

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am 10 minute into a train journey, I settle down to take another crack at my problem and I almost immediately see whats wrong...

..I am missing ".values" in "_data.columns"
The IF statements should infact read:

```
if str(a) in str(_data['LAT'].values) and str(b) in str(_data.columns.value):
```

amazing how fresh eyes make a difference; annoying how much time i wasted yesterday